# Using Python Replace() with JSON object

Tags: python, json, replace

So, I have a JSON object that consists of multiple Facebook messages I am reading in.  Within the messages object I do call replace a few times to remove \n and change the time stamp as shown below.

```
messages = ([msg['created_time'].replace('T', ' ').replace('+0000', ''), msg.get('message', 'Key "message" is not present.').replace('\n', ' ').encode('utf8'),  msg['from']['id']] for msg in js.get('data', []))
```

I have a whole list of words I would actually like to remove from the message text at this point; however, I do not want to break the object apart so replace seems like a good choice.  I tried to put all the words in a list like this:

```
 ignore = ["you","all","has","can","that", "the", "what", "with", "and", "to", "this", "would","from", "your", "which", "while", "these", "when", "way", "like", "been", "will", "look"]
```

I can not just insert this like into the first argument in replace as I would need to have something to the feel of for each word in ignore replace...

Does anyone have any recommendations? Could I use a buffer and feed the whole buffer into replace? Is there a different method I could use?  Do I need to make a replace for each word (this seems sloppy)?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather parse the JSON and perform the replacement safely in the section of the message where it requires it?

Comment: So a message like "Are you all coming to the party" would be fed to this replace method and it would return "Are coming party"?

Comment: Paulo with the current method we are just using write_csv('fb_file.csv', messages, append=True) to output the whole object.  We were trying to avoid breaking it down to parse it as the pull will be running for awhile and this is a lot faster for the amount of data in the object.

Comment: Jason: pretty much.  This isn't the final list, it will definitely get longer.  However, the whole point is to take out all the words that we  don't need to store.  We just want the words that will aid in our analysis.

Comment: @Babs: You're writing a single-line CSV file with all of your messages as columns within it? That seems like an odd data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can not just insert this like into the first argument in replace as I would need to have something to the feel of for each word in ignore replace…

No, but you can write a simple function that chains up a bunch of `.replace` calls:

```
def replaceall(s, olds, replacement):
    for old in olds:
        s = s.replace(old, replacement)
    return s
```

---

This would probably be more efficiently done with a regexp. If there's a major performance problem doing the multiple `replace` calls, now it is a good time to learn the basics of regexp; if not, don't worry about it.

The basic idea—which will work if you're sure that none of your replacement strings have any regexp special characters in them—goes like this:

```
rignore = re.compile('|'.join(ignore))
def ignoreall(s):
    return rignore.sub(s, '')
```

Besides being faster for cases like this, regexp has the advantage of being more powerful. If you later decide you only want to replace complete words (for some good definition of "word"), that will be a relatively easy change. And if you then want to handle removing the preceding space when the left boundary is a space, again, not hard.

---

> Could I use a buffer and feed the whole buffer into replace?

Yes, but this will get difficult, because words to replace can always span the boundaries of one buffer to the next, meaning they won't be in either one. If all of your replacement strings have some unique boundary, like a whitespace or any non-letter or something, you can split off the last part of the buffer and hold onto it until the next buffer, and then doing a buffer at a time will work.

Whether or not this is a useful optimization is something you'll have to measure—or, if everything is fast enough, not bother with. But it definitely won't simplify things.

However, if you have a "whole thing" that has nice boundaries that you can read into memory and process all at once, instead of piece by piece or buffer by buffer (which may or may not be appropriate for your use case), then it *will* simplify things, and likely speed them up as well (at the cost of using more memory, and delaying any processing until a "whole thing" is available, which may or may not cost more than you save).

Comment: Thank you! I will give your ideas a try and see where I get. =)